# Stability of second order linear systems

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

> $\frac{dx}{dt} =-3x + 6y$
>
> $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2x - 4y$
>
> I found the Eigenvalues to be 0 and -7

The solutions says it’s a stable on line X=2y. How do I know this/ work this out?

Comment: Show your work, it's fairly straightforward, have you tried to find out the eigen-pair $(\lambda,v)$ of the linear system ? what do you think the eigen-direction signifies?

Comment: If one of the eigenvalues is zero then the center manifold is one-dimensional. This manifold is described by the line $y = \frac x2$ and is stable.

Comment: @Cesareo thank you so if I get an eigenvalue of 0 is it always in the line $y=\frac{x}{2}$? Or does it differ depending on the eigenvectors?